# How to remove extra spaces from a specific string?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, replace, tags

I have a string like the one below:

```
Ireland, UK, United States of America,     Belgium, Germany   , Some     Country, ...
```

I need help with `Regex` or `String.Replace` function to remove extra spaces so that result would be like:

```
Ireland,UK,United States of America,Belgium,Germany,Same Country,
```

Thank you.

Comment: OMG that was easy ... didn't think of that. Thank you

Comment: Just split with a comma, trim, and `String.Join` back.

Comment: Well, not sure because you have `Some       Country` with many spaces and in the expected output `Same Country` with just one space. Is that true? I guess `String.Join(",", "Ireland, UK, United States of America,     Belgium, Germany   , Some     Country,".Split(","c).Select(Function(m) m.Trim()).ToArray())` won't work then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by splitting the input with a comma, then trimming and shrinking multiple spaces into 1, and `String.Join`ing back.

Just showing how it can be done using LINQ:

```
Console.Write(String.Join(",", _
    "Ireland, UK, United States of America,     Belgium, Germany   , Some     Country," _
     .Split(","c) _
     .Select(Function(m) Regex.Replace(m.Trim(), "\p{Zs}{2,}", " ")) _
     .ToArray()))
```

The key thing is `Regex.Replace(m.Trim(), "\p{Zs}{2,}", " ")` where multiple spaces are shrunk into 1.

Result: `Ireland,UK,United States of America,Belgium,Germany,Some Country,`

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer written by stribizhev is good for this situation, I want to take advantage from this opportunity to highlight the (negative) impact on performance associated with using regex for simple tasks.

ALTERNATIVE NOTABLY FASTER (x2) THAN REGEX (which is always pretty slow when dealing with these situations)

My approach is based on recursive removal of blank spaces. I created two versions: a first one with a conventional loop (`withoutRegex`) and a second one relying on LINQ (`withoutRegex2`; actually, it is identical to the stribizhev's answer except for the `Regex` part).

```
Private Function withoutRegex(input As String) As String

    Dim output As String = ""

    Dim temp() = input.Split(","c)
    For i As Integer = 0 To temp.Length - 1
        output = output & recursiveSpaceRemoval(temp(i).Trim()) & If(i < temp.Length - 1, ",", "")
    Next

    Return output

End Function

Private Function withoutRegex2(input As String) As String

    Return String.Join(",", _
    input _
    .Split(","c) _
    .Select(Function(x) recursiveSpaceRemoval(x.Trim())) _
    .ToArray())

End Function

Private Function recursiveSpaceRemoval(input As String) As String

    Dim output As String = input.Replace("  ", " ")

    If output = input Then Return output
    Return recursiveSpaceRemoval(output)

End Function
```

To prove my point, I created the following testing framework:

```
Dim input As String = "Ireland, UK, United States of America,     Belgium, Germany   , Some     Country"
Dim output As String = ""

Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim countMax As Integer = 20
Dim with0 As Long = 0
Dim without As Long = 0
Dim without2 As Long = 0

While count < countMax

    count = count + 1
    Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    output = withRegex(input)
    sw.Stop()
    with0 = with0 + sw.ElapsedTicks

    sw = New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    output = withoutRegex(input)
    sw.Stop()
    without = without + sw.ElapsedTicks

    sw = New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    output = withoutRegex2(input)
    sw.Stop()
    without2 = without2 + sw.ElapsedTicks

End While

MessageBox.Show("With: " & with0.ToString)
MessageBox.Show("Without: " & without.ToString)
MessageBox.Show("Without 2: " & without2.ToString)
```

Where `withRegex` refers to the stribizhev's answer, that is:

```
Private Function withRegex(input As String) As String

    Return String.Join(",", _
    input _
    .Split(","c) _
    .Select(Function(m) Regex.Replace(m.Trim(), "\p{Zs}{2,}", " ")) _
    .ToArray())

End Function
```

This is a simplistic testing framework which analyses very quick actions, where every single bit matters (the point of the 20 loop iterations is precisely trying to improve the reliability of the measurements a bit). That is: the results are affected even by changing the order in which the methods are being called.

In any case, the differences among methods have remained more or less consistent across all my tests. The average values I got after some tests are:

```
With: 2500-2700
Without: 1100-1300
Without2: 900-1200
```

NOTE: as far as this is a generic critic to regex's performance (at least, in simple enough situations which might be easily replaced with alternatives on the lines of what I am showing here), any advice about how to improve it (regex's performance) in .NET will be more than welcome. But please, avoid generic unclear statements and be as specific as possible (e.g., by suggesting changes in the proposed testing framework).

Comment: With a compiled regex that is declared as static readonly, there is no issue with performance.

Comment: @stribizhev How I do that? A public static (shared) variable readonly? I want to test the best Regex conditions and confirm/dismiss my assumptions. Please, help me!

Comment: @stribizhev There you have a ready-to-use testing framework. Modify it as much as you want and show me (the OP and future readers) how to improve regex's performance. I am writing this post because I think that it is relevant, if you prove that it is not, I would delete it (also would learn how to use regex properly and might even change my approach on this front in the near future).

Comment: Kind of surprising behaviours(s)! Anyway... the point is clear (regex is clearly slower in this kind of contexts + a quicker recursive alternative) and as far as not too many people seem to be fully aware about this fact, I will let this answer here for the time being.

Comment: You got so involved with testing the performance that overlooked the fact that our solutions differ: mine removes all Unicode spaces (e.g. hard space `&#0160;`) while yours removes only regular 32-code space. Well, I agree that just removing a 32-space any non-regex solution will be faster. Still, using a regex when we do not know what spaces await us in the input string is a life-savior.

Comment: @stribizhev Sorry to correct you, but I didn't focus on a very specific issue by forgetting about another one, because honestly I am not sure what you are talking about. With blank spaces in .NET I have always used " " as string and " "c (or ' ' in C#) as character and haven't ever had a single issue. Could you please show me an example where the difference you are pointing out is being highlighted? As said in my answer (in the last update), this is not just about this specific case, but a behaviour which I have been observing with regex in general. If I am wrong I would love to know about it.

Comment: @stribizhev In any case, what I am not understanding too well is the fact of being extremely clear on my position (i.e., code you can test and modify as much as you want; in fact, I have asked you about specific corrections to help me and future readers to know how to maximise regex and, consequently, to improve the reliability of my conclusions as much as possible) and being systematically ignored. Or being answered with abstract statements/claims whose point is not clear (and well... your answer is +4 now). I don't think that all this is neither fair nor right.

Comment: I do not understand why people vote for it that much. Maybe they like short answers. I got a downvote for an efficient, the most correct but rather complex regex 3 days ago. This is not the point. The point is that your approach will not work with [this string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bZs%7d%7b2%2c%7d&i=American+%c2%a0Eagle).

Comment: @stribizhev I have copied your string into my code and it worked perfectly. As said, I haven't ever had any issue by relying on " " to recognise blank spaces with any kind of inputs. On the other hand, the specific character being affected doesn't have any kind of impact on performance. The big difference is that functions like replace (showing an equivalent performance with any input characters) + loop (or LINQ) are faster than regex, because it implies to account for a much more complex reality (worthy when dealing with more difficult formats, but not here).

Comment: @stribizhev I seriously don't want to continue in this line. If you are so sure that regex performance is equivalent (even better) to what I proposed, you should write a code proving it (as I did). Honestly, I wouldn't mind to be proven wrong. I want to improve my knowledge (and help others to improve theirs) and, consequently, wouldn't ever defend something which is not right. These are my ideas at this point; but I do recognise my limited understand of regex and do accept any corrections of my assumptions on this front. But please via code (with reproduceable inputs).

Comment: *If you are so sure that regex performance is equivalent (even better) to what I proposed, you should write a code proving it (as I did).* - I never said it was equivalent or better, just said *there is no issue with performance*. I am using regexps intensively and have no trouble. I agree your non-regex solution is best if only regular spaces are to be taken into account. Note that `.Trim()` does remove all Unicode whitespace.

Comment: @stribizhev I am not saying that you should have any trouble with regex. All what I am saying is that, for simple situations, regex tends to be notably slower than alternatives based on functions like replace/split + loops. In this specific case, I don't see any difference in functionalities among the shown methods (mine & yours); even if you could propose input conditions where such differences happen (I would be grateful for any sample code clearly showing this point), my approach could easily be fixed by accounting for the given character (and this wouldn't have any impact on performance).